# VSE sync audio beat to clip length

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I like to make a video with a bunch of images and an underlying music track. Now I would like to sync the length of the images to the beat of the music. I know that there is a Bake Sound to F-Curve, but I have no idea how to use the data of that f-curve to an array of clips and influence the length of those clips.

I tried google search, but didn't found any solution for my problem. Maybe anyone has done something similar or has an idea. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you'll find this useful: https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-audio-to-markers/639081

Answer (score 0):

There is a option in <kbd>N</kbd>-panel in VSE editor "Draw waveform":

[image]

If you activate it blender will draw audio waveform on selected sound clip:

[image]

You can use it as a guide for trimming and moving video-clips

Comment: Thanks, but that would still involve that I manually move the lengths of the clips. I was hoping that there is a way where I could maybe map two thresholds to this wavedata and then everytime they switch a new clip is created. I hope you understand what I'm talking about :)

Comment: You could try these add-ons to do the beat detection in Audacity, export the labels and import them as markers into Blender(I haven't testet it): https://blenderartists.org/t/audacity-labels-to-timeline-markers-script/576619